# Show count of posts in subcategory on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

How would I show a count of only those posts found within a subcategory to be displayed in the archive page of that subcategory?

So if I navigate to the `Food > Fruits` archive page I want to display a count of how many posts are filed under just under `Fruits`

Somehow I thought this would be straightforward but it's not.

I have no code to start off the conversation with. I've tried about six different options I found here and online but none seem to be right.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [get_queried_object();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) on the archive template.

```
<?php $category = get_queried_object(); echo $category->count; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it manually like this:

```
<?php

    $categories = get_categories(array('type' => 'post', 'include' => 19, 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC'));

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        echo '<p>' . $category->count . '</p>';
    }

?>
```

You'll need to change the number 19 in `'include' => 19` to whatever the category ID is that you want to show a post count for.

You could try to automate it by adding something like this to your category archive template:

```
<?php

    $currCat = get_the_category();
    $category_id = $currCat[0]->cat_ID;                             
    $categories = get_categories(array('type' => 'post', 'include' => $category_id, 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC'));

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        echo '<p>' . $category->count . '</p>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: This one returned additional sums, which is a problem most people ran into. The resulting count tallies up all the instances where a same post appears in other subcategories. Kinda hard to explain, sorry! But thanks for taking the time.